# mysqli_connect vs mysqli_real_connect

Tags: php, mysqli

I read the [doumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) But I don't understand the difference exactly.

What difference does the connection object make in this?  I didn't find any posts.

I misunderstood it. Flags are not present in both. Why didn't they add flags as part of `mysqli_connect`? Any specific reasons? Which one should I use?

Comment: "flags are present in both". Are you sure?

Comment: @Nanne - Sorry. Please see the edits

Answer (score 8):

`mysqli_real_connect()` and `mysqli_connect` is different in way that

`mysqli_real_connect()` accepts a lot more options than `mysqli_connect`

For example I am building a health-check script for my Loadbalancer and I want set the very low connection timeout.

Now the connection timeout has to be set using:

`mysqli_options()` with the option name `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`

Now the thing with `mysqli_options()` is that this should be called after mysqli_init() and before mysqli_real_connect().

`mysqli_connect` cannot be used for this purpose.

Hope this explanation helps.

```
<?php
//create the object
$connection = mysqli_init();

//specify the connection timeout
$connection->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 3);

//specify the read timeout
$connection->options(MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, 3);

//initiate the connection to the server, using both previously specified timeouts
$connection->real_connect('server', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

This function differs from mysqli_connect():

`mysqli_real_connect()` needs a valid object which has to be created by function `mysqli_init()`.

With the `mysqli_options()` function you can set various options for connection.

There is a flags parameter.

Comment: And mysqli_connect vs mysqli_init?

Comment: mysqli_real_connect() needs a valid object which has to be created by function mysqli_init().

Answer (score 4):

With mysqli_real_connect you can test if the initialization of the mysqli object was successful and set any [mysqli_options](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) before connecting.

Comment: Then why do we need mysqli_connect

Comment: Please explain a bit more

Comment: Most of the time you won't need to test whether the mysqli object initialized properly, and most people are happy with the default options, so you just use mysqli_connect.